# AWS Win Tasks aren't running after server restart via Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks

I have coded a simple task scedule that turns the AWS Windows server off and a simple Lambda code to turn the stopped instaces on, see code:

```py
import time
import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # boto3 client
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')

    # getting instance information
    describeInstance = client.describe_instances()
    #print("eddie", describeInstance["Reservations"][0]["Instances"][0]["State"]["Name"])

    InstanceId = []
    # fetchin instance id of the running instances
    for i in describeInstance['Reservations']:
        for instance in i['Instances']:
            if instance["State"]["Name"] == "stopped":
                InstanceId.append(instance['InstanceId'])


    client.start_instances(InstanceIds=InstanceId)

    """looping through instance ids
    for instanceid in InstanceId:
        # command to be executed on instance
        client.start_instances(InstanceIds=InstanceId)
        print(output)"""

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Thanks from Srce Cde!')
    }
```

I have several tasks on my task scheduler that run Python scripts but after the activation those tasks arent running even when the server in running.

Note, I have tried to set "run whether logged on or not" on all of them but recived (0x1) errors related to privileges on those tasks

Does anyone know how to solve this? Is there any other way to turn off and on EC2 AWS win server in night time to save on billing

Comment: The issue does not seem related to Lambda. It is related to Windows not running Scheduled Tasks after Power On. You might be best asking this at: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems that you are right I just need to find a way to workaround that